# Reloading a table without reloading the webpage

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I currently have a table that you can add / delete / remove all the items from but in order to actually see that you have removed an item or cleared the table I need to reload the webpage. I was wondering if there was another way of just reloading the table instead of reloading the webpage

Comment: A quick solution could be to use [jQuery load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/). This will make an ajax request to your current page, then you can simple replace the table element with the table from the ajax response.

Comment: You'll need to use AJAX.

Comment: Yes there is, but without seeing your code, i dont know what you actually need to do

Comment: Why don't you just remove the cells corresponding to those items ?

Comment: you will need ajax for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For deleting a row:

```
 $('#myTableRow').remove();
```

This works fine if your row has an id, such as:

```
<tr id="myTableRow"><td>blah</td></tr>
```

For adding :

```
$('#myTable > tbody:last').append('<tr>...</tr><tr>...</tr>');
```

And assuming tat your item is in a row :)

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use `AJAX` to get data back from the server.

In your server, you would have a page that serves `json` containing relevant data, and you will parse it and update the page.

So for example, you could route `mytable/update` to a method in your server, and you would call it like so:

`jQuery.ajax('/mytable/update)`

The callback would have the actual `json`. Be wary of [CSRF](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29)

However, you mentioned that your table only has an add and delete. Is there data coming from the server? You might be able to replicate your code from the server in the client itself so you could just make the changes themselves with javascript, which would help reduce server load.

Comment: He said it's only for view purposes, I think he handled the server side !

Comment: @Sekai It wasn't really clear what he was asking, I just gave out the general answer to his worries. For all we know there might be new data coming in from the server.